# JSF e JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, primefaces, jboss, xhtml

Estou com a seguinte duvida:
Como o JSF trabalha com o JavaScript ?

Vou ser mais especifico. Eu estou em um projeto onde estou usando JSF (primefaces), porém não consigo fazer algo simples com JavaScript, que seria um

```
var btnCarregaAnexo = document.querySelector('carregaAnexo')
btnCarregaAnexo.style.display = 'none'
```

Apresenta um erro no console, de que a variável `btnCarregaAnexo` esta `"null"`.

Porém no `button` que estou querendo pegar, está com `"id" = carregaAnexo;`

Já testei também com `getElementById`, mas sem sucesso...

Então conclusão, o JSF (primefaces) ou o JBoss, que estou utilizando, interfere no caminho dos ID'S? Não consigo de maneira nenhuma pegar um componente com JS...

Obrigado, desculpe se não me expressei da melhor maneira, mas estou a disposição para conversarmos.

---

Alterei para realizar a seleção por classes CSS e o erro persiste…

XHTML

```
<p:commandButton id=“carrega1” styleClass="botaoAnexo"
value="Carregar Declaração"
title="Carregar Declaração e/ou Diploma de Conclusão do Ensino Médio"
onclick=“editarArquivo1.show();“
rendered=”#{empty atletaCidadaoController.atletaCidadao.tipoArquivo1}”/>
```

JavaScript

```
var btnCarregaAnexo = document.querySelector('botaoAnexo');
            btnCarregaAnexo.style.display ='block';
```

CSS

```
.botaoAnexo{
    display: none;
}
```

ERRO NO CONSOLE

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘style’ of null
```

Comment: Em qual posição você colocou esse script? No head ou no final do body?

Comment: Posta seu código

Comment: Bom, não sei qual o seu conhecimento de **Javascript**, mas, não é assim que o `querySelector` funciona, pelo seu exemplo o correto seria **querySelector('#carregaAnexo')**.

Comment: Então LeAndrade, eu testei tambem com '#' porem apresenta mesmo erro, postei logo abaixo com uma tentativa de pegar pela classe CSS, mas apresenta o mesmo erro no console... 

Laerte o script esta no fim do body !, mas ja testei tambem com o script no inicio do body, testei tambem colocar o script em outra file... e importar ele no html, mas sempre mesmo erro...

Comment: Os ids dos componentes jsf são gerados dinamicamente. Você precisaria definir uma class e usar o findByClassName.

Comment: vc não considerou usar o componente de upload de arquivos do primefaces?

Comment: AdrianoGomes, estou utilizando o componente upload do prime, porém a versao do prime qe utilizo é uma versão mais antiga, e esta versao não é acessivel(deficientes visuais)... E quero tentar fazer com que fique acessivel utilizando javaScript, porém nem o basico esta dando certo, não sei se o Jboss interfere, ou primefaces não esta deixando eu pegar componentes cm JS.

Comment: Vc está tentando fazer algo via javascript que eu creio ser mais fácil via EL. O que exatamente vc precisa fazer? Controlar a renderização do commandButton?

Answer (score 0):

Se vc precisa controlar o style de um componente, tente usar EL. O exemplo abaixo exibe um div em escala de cinza se ele estiver aguardando encerramento (o `controlador.aguardandoEncerramento` é um booleano):

```
<h:panelGroup id="pnlFoto">
    <ui:param name="escalaDeCinza" value="#{controlador.aguardandoEncerramento ? 'filter: grayscale(1);' : ''}" />
    <p:outputPanel style="height: 100%; background: url(/imagens/user.gif) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size: cover; #{escalaDeCinza}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Nesse caso, só é necessário fazer um update no `pnlFoto` para alterar o style.